# timthumb cache image path

Tags: php, caching, thumbnails

i have cache set to TRUE and my cache folder even set to 777 for now.

But when i view image path it still shows the filename and path to the original?

Is it not supposed to show me the path to the cached image instead?

Timthumb settings:

```
define ('CACHE_SIZE', 100);             // number of files to store before clearing cache
define ('CACHE_CLEAR', 20);                 // maximum number of files to delete on each cache clear
define ('CACHE_USE', TRUE);                 // use the cache files? (mostly for testing)
define ('VERSION', '1.25');                 // version number (to force a cache refresh)
define ('DIRECTORY_CACHE', '../cache');     // cache directory
define ('MAX_WIDTH', 5000);                 // maximum image width
define ('MAX_HEIGHT', 3000);                // maximum image height
define ('ALLOW_EXTERNAL', FALSE);           // allow external website (override security precaution - not advised!)
define ('MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');                // set PHP memory limit
define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 12582912);         // file size limit to prevent possible DOS attacks (roughly 12 megabytes)
define ('CURL_TIMEOUT', 10);                    // timeout duration. Tweak as you require (lower = better)
```

Issue im having is the url image path is this:

```
http://mydomain.com/includes/crop.php?src=images/art/urban/alleyway.jpg&h=250&w=958&q=95
```

And i thought with Cache enabled it would be this:

```
http://mydomain.com/cache/a051f7c9e5d039708ac92dece9a07901.jpg
```

Please tell me if im doing something wrong.

Cheers
John

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, TimThumb will still run the PHP processing to at least evaluate if there is a thumb in existence. So no, it should still have the same src on your img.